# Why are reference template parameters not deduced automatically?

Tags: c++, reference

In the following example, I'd intuitively expect the call to `inc(iref)` to invoke the inc-function with `T=int&`, since that's the type of `iref`. However, it seems that the `&` is dropped when the variable is passed to a function, thus leading to `T=int` in the case of both `inc(i)` as well as `inc(iref)`. The behaviour I'd expect only happens when explicitly specifying the template parameter as reference.

```
template<typename T> 
void inc(T t) {
    t++;
}

int main() {
    int i = 41;
    int& iref = i;

    iref++;
    std::cout << i << " " << iref << std::endl; // prints 42 42, as expected

    inc(i);
    std::cout << i << " " << iref << std::endl; // still prints 42 42, as expected

    inc(iref);
    std::cout << i << " " << iref << std::endl; // prints 42 42, instead of 43 43

    inc<int&>(iref);
    std::cout << i << " " << iref << std::endl; // now finally prints 43 43
}
```

So, my questions are:

- Why is the reference seemingly turned into a 'bare' value when being passed via `inc(iref)`? What's the process behind it?
- Why does it work this way / what's the rationale behind that design decision? Would there be any problems or negative consequences if it worked the way I intuitively expected?

Comment: How do you pass by copy with your way ?

Comment: And you miss `inc<int&>(i);`.

Comment: The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786736/template-type-deduction-of-reference) is perfect, not 100% sure if it should be dupe closed though.

Comment: And there is also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12052674/4342498)

Comment: I expected than I can use `i` and `iref` interchangeably. Your way would make aliasing dangerous: `int& short_i = very_long_instance.member_i; use(short_i);`.

Comment: *"Why does it work this way / what's the rationale behind that design decision?"* I guess that hasn't been answered yet, I wouldn't close this question.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo: Exactly, that was the main motivation for posting this question in the first place. The first part of the question seems to be answered in the question linked by NathanOliver: C++ treats all expressions as having non-reference type.

Comment: Because normally it makes more sense for the template writer, rather than template users, to decide whether the template implements pass by value or pass by reference.

Answer (score -1):

The reference is stripped of it's reference value because if it isn't iref is ambiguous otherwise(int& or int). It is designed this way so that so that you may overload it like:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> 
void inc(T& t) {
    t++;
}

int main() {
    int i = 41;
    int& iref = i;

    inc(iref);
    std::cout << iref << std::endl;
}
```